# Repeating the string and calculate the width of the string

Tags: jquery, css

The script already can calculate the width of the script based on user's input, It can also calculate the width of the string. Now what I'm trying to achieve, is when the user repeat the string for example, "A", and then string "A" is repeat 6times, so it will be "AAAAAA", here is where is problem occur, the function I made on repeating the string does not work. Basically, the string will be repeated, let's say 6times, and then the width of the string will be calculated. Any idea on this ??

```
$.fn.textWidth = function(text, font) {

    var fontsize = $('#fntSize').val();

    if (!$.fn.textWidth.fakeEl) $.fn.textWidth.fakeEl = $('<span>').hide().appendTo(document.body);
    $.fn.textWidth.fakeEl.text(text || this.val() || this.text()).css({'font-size':fontsize+'px'});
    return $.fn.textWidth.fakeEl.width();
};

$.fn.repeat = function( num )
{
    return new Array( num + 1 ).join( this );
}

$("[name='txtLine[]']").each(function(){

    $(this).css({"background-color":"#fff"}).siblings('span.errorMsg').text('');;



    if (!this.value.length) 
    {
        $(this).focus();
        $(this).css({"background-color":"#f6d9d4"}).siblings('span.errorMsg').text('Please add a word.');
        event.preventDefault();
    }


    if($(this).repeat(6).textWidth() >= 490)
    {
        alert("Too long");
        event.preventDefault();


    }

}); 


});
```

Comment: The problem description is very vague and your question could use some more information.

Comment: What is `return isTrue` returning from? It's not inside any function.

Comment: That if for return false, I forgot to removed it,. sorry. I updated the codes

Comment: You still have unmatched close braces and parentheses at the end.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `this.value.repeat(6)`?

Answer (score 0):

`$(this).repeat(6).textWidth()` should be `this.value.repeat(6).textWidth()`. `$(this)` is a jQuery object, not a string.

And if you want to define a method that operates on ordinary strings, you need to add it to the `String` prototype, not define it as a jQuery method:

```
String.prototype.repeat = function( num )
{
    return new Array( num + 1 ).join( this );
}
```

Comment: I'm getting error Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function 
that is on repeat,. the function I made.

Comment: Can you please check this jsfiddle,. I tried to do it here, but somehow it's not working. 
http://jsfiddle.net/r6Df4/1/

Comment: It should be `.repeat(6).length > 100` to test the length of the string.

Comment: Why are you defining jQuery and String prototype functions inside your click handler?

Comment: You also had a typo, `$("[name='txtLine[]']")` should be `$("[name='textLine[]']")`. Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/r6Df4/4/

Comment: I see,. so there is no need for function textWidth?

Comment: O wait,. length will only calculate the number of string, not the width

Comment: You weren't using either function. `textWidth` should also be defined as a String prototype function, not a jQuery function.

Comment: Now it's getting confusing. I did change the $.fn.textWidth = function(text, font) to String.prototype.textwidth, but the codes inside the function having an error

Comment: Well, yeah, because that function is designed to work with jQuery objects, since it uses `this.val()` and `this.text()`. You need to write different functions for strings and jQuery objects.

Comment: String.prototype.textWidth = function(font) {
  var fontsize = $('#fntSize').val(); var f = font || '12px arial',
      o = $('<div>' + this + '</div>')
            .css({'position': 'absolute', 'float': 'left', 'white-space': 'nowrap', 'visibility': 'hidden', 'font': f, 'font-size':fontsize+'px'})
            .appendTo($('body')),
      w = o.width();

  o.remove();

  return w;
}

I hope this works on calculating the width of string.